# Search for particular format of date in saved search

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to find the customers whose birthday is in next month and the way the birthdays of customers will be entered at the stores is, they just ask for day and month and put in the current year for year.

So, when I', trying to do the search as next month it seem like I can only search with in a range that include year, which don't work in this case.

I've tried the below with search field set to `is february` but it don't automate the search as I have to change the month every month

`TO_CHAR({custentity_spos_date1},'MONTH, YYYY')`

Does some one have any idea how to include only month in search so that I can search for customers who's birthday is in a particular month?

Answer (score 1):

```
case 
    when to_char({today}, 'MM') = '12' then
        case 
            when to_char({custentity_spos_date1}, 'MM') = '01' then 1 
            else 0 
        end
    when to_number(to_char({custentity_spos_date1}, 'MM')) = to_number(to_char({today}, 'MM')) + 1 then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

equal to 1

[image: Formula filter criteria]

The filter basically says if the month of the current date is 12, then match any record where the month of the date field is 1, otherwise match any record where the month of the date field is equal to the month of the current date + 1.

There may be an easier way, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL formatting and ADD_MONTHS functions to compare only the month component of the date:

`CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({custentity_spos_date1}, 'MM') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 1),'MM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Equal to 1.